# How to unset unchecked checkbox values in $_SESSION array in PHP

Tags: php, session, pagination

I am having pagination with PHP, and am having next and previous page SUBMIT buttons, hence if the user checks 2 values on page 1, I store it in a session variable, and when he visits back I use `in_array` and echo out the value. but how do I unset the value in array if the user unchecks? am not able to unset the value in session array if user has unchecked the checkbox.

I guess my explanation is crystal clear but still if some needs the code than here it is

```
if(!empty($_POST['rec_num'])) {
        if(empty($_SESSION['checks_selected_for_records'])) {
               //If session array is empty than directly add all record numbers in
               //this session
           $_SESSION['checks_selected_for_records'] = $_POST['rec_num'];
       }
        //If a new value is seen and is not in array than add it            
       foreach ($_POST['rec_num'] as $check_rec_num) {
        if(!in_array($check_rec_num, $_SESSION['checks_selected_for_records'])) {
           array_push($_SESSION['checks_selected_for_records'], $check_rec_num);
       }
   }
} 

//Handle Redirects For Pagination
if (isset($_POST['next_page']) || isset($_POST['last_page']) || isset($_POST['first_page']) || isset($_POST['previous_page'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['next_page_link'])) {
            redirect_to($_POST['next_page_link']);
        } elseif (isset($_POST['last_page'])) {
            redirect_to($_POST['last_page_link']);
        } elseif (isset($_POST['first_page'])) {
            redirect_to($_POST['first_page_link']);
        } elseif (isset($_POST['previous_page'])) {
            redirect_to($_POST['previous_page_link']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you only want to know how to unset the php SESSION variable or do you need javaskript to trigger the unset ?

Comment: unset a session var is easy, I want the rec numbers to be unset if they are unchecked, and I want pure PHP solution

Comment: a now i am getting to it you want to kick out the value of the array if unselected

Comment: yap, exactly, and I've to save it in a session because am using pagination and after user is done with selection he can generate a report based on these rec nums

Comment: look if i got you right in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You remove a value from an array by using array_search

```
if(($key = array_search($del_val,  $_SESSION['checks_selected_for_records'])) !== false) {
   unset($_SESSION['checks_selected_for_records'][$key]);
 }
```

Comment: I know this but how should I get the unchecked values?

Comment: The scenario is that the user sends the from containing the changed checked checkboxes a 2nd time ? Then I would simply drop the whole old Array and create a new one

Comment: I cant drop entire array as some values are selected on page 2, that's the whole problem

Comment: I would simply store the values from the 2nd pages in a seconds $_Session[] index ==> 2nd var, otherwise it will be hard to compare

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox">
</form>

<?php
  $_SESSION['mycheckbox'] = isset($_POST['mycheckbox']);
// OR
  if( ! isset($_POST['mycheckbox']) ) {
    unset($_SESSION['mycheckbox']);
  } else {
    $_SESSION['mycheckbox'] = $_POST['mycheckbox'];
  }
```

Comment: there are multiple checkboxes and I want to unset array value, not the whole session